# Isoclines for three-dimensional case?

Tags: derivatives, systems-of-equations

I have a system of three differential kinetic equations with three variables. I want to solve it using phase plain method. I know how to solve it in case of two variables, but don’t know what to do if there are 3 variables.

It can be solved finding isoclines, for each angle, for example if we have system

$$\dfrac{dx}{dt}=4x+3y$$

$$\dfrac{dy}{dt}=23+y$$

To find vertical isocline we need to do

$$\dfrac{23+y}{4x+3y}=tg(90^•)$$

We will get a formula, that describes an isocline line.

If have three equations with three variables, how to get isoclines?

Comment: You set both $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} = \frac{d z}{dt}/ \frac{dx}{dt}$ and $\frac{\partial z}{\partial y} = \frac{d z}{dt}/ \frac{dy}{dt}$ equal to some constant. This gives you two planes in $\mathbb{R}^3$. The intersection of these is an isocline.

Comment: @LukasRollier I will try

Comment: @LukasRollier, okay but for 0 degree isocline I will get a system $$\delta z=0$$ $$\delta z=0$$ which gives solution z=f(x,y). My math bad, and the only declaration type of 3D lines I can deal with is when I have system $$x=f(z)$$ $$y=g(z)$$ And from for each z I can get each dot of the line, i.e. (x,y,z)=(f(z),g(z),z). How to draw line if I have z=f(x,y) ?

Comment: @LukasRollier oh, I just realized that I am find the intersection of the same plane with itself. Then it is more senseless. What to do?